# How to chek column date in a table 10 minutes less than current time

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to check time in column of a table is less than 10 min from current time.
I want to check in where clause in Laravel query.

Comment: `... WHERE your_column < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE...`

Answer (score 1):

Lets find a datetime older than 10 minutes from current datetime using PHP. Lets say $formatted_date in our code.
And than find all the records having datetime less than $formatted_date. Please look below and let me know if you have any query.

```
$date = new DateTime;
$current_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date->modify('-10 minutes');
$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$result = DB::table('table_name')->where('datecolumn','<=',$formatted_date)->get();
```

Another way is:

```
$result = DB::table('table_name')->where(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'datecolumn',$current_date),'<=',10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a where clause like

```
SELCT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOL < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```